# Need some tips with constructing a matrix from a given two- dimensional array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

well I need to do the first constrctor and I was given in the method an array that i need to copy from.
the method is - 
public Matrix(int[][] array)

what i tried is this :

```
public Matrix(int[][] array)
{
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++ ) // running all over the rows
    {
        for ( int j=0; j < array[i].length; j++ ) // running all over the columns
        {

            _matrixArray[i][j]=array[i][j]; 


        }    
    }
}
```

it says that im pointing to null? im trying to avoid alliasing so yeah, might need some help with this question please : )

Comment: Is this `_matrixArray[i][j]` initialized anytime?

Comment: Indeed it is, its a private variable of class Matrix :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the array before adding elements to it. For example:

```
class Matrix {

    private int[][] _matrixArray;


    public Matrix(int[][] array)
    {
        this._matrixArray = new int[array.length][array[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                this._matrixArray[i][j]=array[i][j]; 
            }    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yay! thank you very much, tbh i knew that but didnt know how lol :D once again thanks :)<3

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `matrix` first. But note, the `[][]` means arrays of arrays, so in general case, different rows could have various coulmns amount.

```
public class Matrix {

    private final int[][] matrix;

    public Matrix(int[][] arr) {
        matrix = new int[arr.length][];

        for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
            matrix[row] = Arrays.copyOf(arr[row], arr[row].length);
    }

}
```